How to include the French offline speech package in the built-in GMS package of the Android software
I want to integrate the French offline speech package into the GMS package so that customers don’t need to download it separately and can use the TTS service. However, I found that SpeechServicesByGoogle.apk downloads the speech package to /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.tts/files/superpacks/fr-fr. Since I can't access the /data directory with user version software, does Google provide a method to include offline speech packages directly?
I tried pre-installing the French speech package to /data, but it disappears after a factory reset. I attempted to add a service in init.rc with 'cp /system/etc/fr-fr /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.tts/files/superpacks/fr-fr', but it didn't work, possibly due to permission issues preventing the copy
